# Generating multiplication table using for loop using Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, for-loop

I am trying to generate multiplication table using for loop in kotlin,
here is my code:

```
       import java.util.Scanner

        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
              val read = Scanner(System.`in`)

              println("Enter any number:")
              var num = read.nextInt()

              for(i in 1..10)
                 var mul = num * i
                 println("$num * $i = $mul")
         }
```

But, after compiling this code, it showing me this error:

> Multiplication.kt:11:26: error: unresolved reference: i
> println("$num * $i = $mul")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for` without brackets will be only valid for **1 following line**. Since you have two lines, you must wrap it:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val read = Scanner(System.`in`)

  println("Enter any number:")
  var num = read.nextInt()

  for(i in 1..10) { // <---
    var mul = num * i
    println("$num * $i = $mul")
  } // <---
}
```

Comment: as a note, one could also do `(1..10).forEach { println("$num * $it = ${num * it}") }` instead of the `for` loop.

Comment: @Alex.T, you can, but that is discouraged in the Kotlin coding conventions. `forEach` is intended for use in a chain of actions on iterables, and is considered less readable than a regular `for`-loop. [Info here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#loops)

Comment: @Tenfour04 that is interesting, I've never noticed that in the docs. Thanks for the info.